# Playspec not picking logger configuration

Tags: logback, playframework-2.6

In my `play` application, I have provided a `logback.xml`. The configuration for controller `AnswerController` is `<logger name="controllers.AnswerController" level="TRACE" additivity="false"> 
<appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/> </logger>`

But when I run my test case, I don't see any logs. Do I need to configure `logback` explicitly? I am using `custom application loader`.

Why are the logs now showing?

Answer (score 0):

I added the `LoggerConfigurator` to my code and it seem to work (still early day to confirm if this will create some side effect. Though I don't the flow of why this makes things work (BTW, I do the same for my customer application loader as well)

```
class AnswerControllerUnitSpec extends PlaySpec with BeforeAndAfterAll with BeforeAndAfterEach with OneAppPerSuiteWithComponents{


  override def beforeEach() = {
    println("------------new test -----------------")
  }

  LoggerConfigurator(context.environment.classLoader).foreach {
    _.configure(context.environment, context.initialConfiguration, Map.empty)
  }
...
}
```